# ffmpeg run with c# avformat_open failed

Tags: c#, audio, merge, ffmpeg

I want to expand the music with ffmpeg on c#

My c# code,

```
   proc2.StartInfo.FileName = "H:\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe";

            proc2.StartInfo.Arguments = "-lavfi amovie=input.mp3:loop=9 C:\\Users\\serhat-pc\\Desktop\\newinput.mp3";



            proc2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            if (!proc2.Start())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error starting");
                return;
            }
            StreamReader reader = proc2.StandardError;
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            proc2.Close();
```

BUT I'm receiving this problem:

[ffmpeg problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nihm.png)

Please help me friends , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by concatenating same file.

Create a text file with content (concat.txt):

```
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'    
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
file '/path/to/input.mp3'
```

then use following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy output.mp3
```